# Move mail code for Outlook not moving last item

Tags: vba, outlook, move, outlook-2010

I am trying to move messages that are marked as **Read** from my `errorMails` folder to my `sentErrors` folder, both of which are within my `mailOne` folder. The current code I have works for most of the mail I have marked as read, but leaves one last read mail alone.

Am I missing something?

```
Public Sub moveToSentFolder()

Dim obj As Object
Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim archiveFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim mailOneFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim sentErrorFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim dumpErrorFolder As Outlook.Folder

Set archiveFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders("Archives")
Set mailOneFolder = archiveFolder.Folders("mailOne")
Set errorFolder = ehealthFolder.Folders("errorMails")
Set dumpErrorFolder = ehealthFolder.Folders("sentErrors")

'Dim Message As MailItem

Set Folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Items = errorFolder.Items

For i = Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

    With Items(i)

        ''Error 438 is returned when .receivedtime is not supported
        On Error Resume Next

        If .UnRead = False Then
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                .Move dumpErrorFolder
            Else
                Err.Clear
            End If
        End If
    MsgBox i 'debug
    End With

Next

'For some reason the commented out code below only seems to move half of all the read mails, so I have to run the macro more than once to clear folder of read mails - this code now unused
'For Each Message In Items
    'If Message.UnRead = False Then
    ''Message.Move dumpErrorFolder
    'i = i + 1
    'End If
'Next Message

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, items can have varying index boundaries - controlled using [`option base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) or `To` clause. In Office, arrays are indexed starting at position 1 (**1-based**), not 0 (*0-based*). You need to change your `FOR` loop to accommodate this change.

```vb
For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
```

As another alternative, you could leverage [`UBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`LBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/t9a7w1ac%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to determine the appropriate index boundaries.

```vb
For i = UBound(Items) To LBound(Items) Step -1
```